# Datagrams seen in Wireshark, not received by Qt UDP Socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, udp

I am writing a Qt (5.6) application that communicates with an FPGA over UDP socket. Packets are being streamed to the PC at 2 KHz (all packets identical size, 1272 bytes). Wireshark shows that packets are being sent, and the UDP header is as expected. The problem is, the Qt UDP Socket that I am using is never receiving these packets. The **readyRead** signal is never called.

Here is a code snippet:

```
UdpConnection::UdpConnection(QObject* parent)
{
    fpgaConnection = QSharedPointer<QUdpSocket>(new QUdpSocket);

    qDebug() << connect(fpgaConnection.data(), &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &UdpConnection::readyRead);

    if (fpgaConnection->bind(QHostAddress("192.168.10.10"), 1920))
    {
        qDebug() << "Successfully Bound!";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "BINDING FAILURE";
    }

    fpgaConnection->connectToHost(QHostAddress("192.168.10.200"), 1919);

    sendArpRequest();
}

void UdpConnection::readyRead()
{
    while (fpgaConnection->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray buffer;
        buffer.resize(fpgaConnection->pendingDatagramSize());

        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        fpgaConnection->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);
        qDebug() << "Message from:" << sender;
        qDebug() << "Message port:" << senderPort;
        qDebug() << buffer;
    }
}
```

- UdpConnection is not running on a separate thread from main. Should it be?
- I am binding successfully, and I would assume that "connectToHost" is working because I'm able to send a message to the remote host.
- The application has been added to the Firewall exception list (again, the ARP handshake proves that they are capable of communicating).
- The interface is a direct ethernet connection between the FPGA and a PC.

Why is Wireshark able to see these messages, but my program is not?

**UPDATE #1**
Wireshark has the 2KHz packets as LLC packets. The Ethernet Header shows a correct Destination (my MAC address), Source Address (hard coded in the FPGA), and Length. The IP header has the Source IP as 192.168.10.200 and the Destination IP as 192.168.10.10, UDP Header has Source Port as 1920 and Destination Port as 1919.

**UPDATE #2**
Wireshark logs: paste.ee/p/98c1H 
As you can see, the packet is repeated and sent from the FPGA at 2KHz. The ARP transmission and reply can be found as the 5th, 10th, and 11th packet.

**UPDATE #3**
The IP packets of the incoming packets have a correct checksum that is NOT being set to 0x0000.

Comment: Are the desired UDP packets actually being sent from `192.168.10.200:1920` to `192.168.10.10:1919`? Can you show the actual UDP packet info from Wireshark?  Do you receive the packets if you remove the call to `connectToHost()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added in Update #1

Comment: @RemyLebeau I receive the packets in Wireshark whether I launch the application or not. As soon as I turn the FPGA on, they show up in Wireshark and begin transmitting immediately.

Comment: It's difficult to help you without seeing the wireshark data. But one comment: the fact that ARP works doesn't mean the firewall is well configured. In fact if what you say is correct, one actual possibility is that the firewall is dropping the datagram. Or maybe the datagram is being dropped for some other reason. You should show iptables as well.

Comment: @rodolk Which Wireshark data specifically would be helpful?

Comment: @MattDavBen basically the one that shows all UDP messages in both direction and ARP messages. Wireshark will create a file with all the traffic.

Comment: @rodolk 
Wireshark logs: paste.ee/p/98c1H 
As you can see, the packet is repeated and sent from the FPGA at 2KHz. The ARP transmission and reply can be found as the 5th, 10th, and 11th packet.

Comment: It should be noted that the checksum is being hard-coded to 0x0000 (because we are using IPv4, the checksum is ignored) and the Identification field is properly iterating.

Comment: If you replace the first argument to bind() with QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, and/or comment out the connectToHost() call, does that make any difference?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the last argument to your connect() call be &UDPConnection::readyRead instead of &FPGA_HardwareInterface::readyRead ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I tried it with AnyIPv4, no dice. It says that I successfully bound to 0.0.0.0, but not 192.168.10.10. Also, that was a typo to reference FPGA_HardwareInterface (that's the real name of my class). It has been corrected.

Comment: Since udp is a kind of connection-less commuication, `connectToHost()` is irrelevant when using `readDatagram()`. Writing should be done using `writeDatagram()`. If you are using `connectToHos()` in native (`QIODevice`) mode you also have to use the corresponding `read()` and `write()`. `readyRead()` should be valid though. Are you sure its not getting called and just does not provide a datagram? Furthermore you do not to happen to have this actually seperated within multiple threads?

Comment: @SebastianLange I am listening on 192.168.10.10:1920 and writing to 192.168.10.200:1919, so I bound to one and connected to the other. Should I be binding to both, then using readDatagram and writeDatagram? Because right now I am successfully able to connect() and write() to the remote port, I just can't receive on the listening port.

Comment: The package you receive is just not a datagram as far as I know. Your size in the ethernet header should be the IPv4-Type followed by the IP-Frame followed by the UDP Header and your payload. Since the UDP Socket tries to interprete complete Datagrams its not giving you any signal to now read a new datagram.

Comment: @SebastianLange Instead of the IPv4 Type (0x800 for UDP), we are using the length of the packet. I assumed that was valid, since it is it was below 1500 (which typically signifies length instead of type). Do you think if we changed that to 0x800, they may be interpreted as UDP datagrams?

Comment: Tried fiddling a semi-valid UDP Datagram as an answer quickly...

Comment: @SebastianLange Plain and simple: could this behavior come from using the frame length rather than the EtherType?

Comment: Fun fact, it does. It actually shows a valid udp package on first view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packet seems not to be a valid UDP Datagram.

**Edit**:

After fiddling with the packet it seem to be enough to change the type in the ethernet header to to IPv4 (0x0800).

It does show a strange **TTL** with a value of 0, but that may be sender related.

**Original Post**:

Instead of your current data you should send like this for having a valid datagram:

**Ethernet Headers w/ IPv4** (14Byte): (as in your implementation, but type IPv4 0x0800), Source, Dest, Type

```
64006a493488 020826283900 0800
```

**IPv4-Headers** (20Byte): Version, Other, Size=1298(0512) UDP + 20, Ident, Flags(0x00), FlagOffset(0), TTL(128), Protocol(17 UDP), Checksum, Source = .10.200, Dest = .10.10

```
45 00 0512 31f0 00 00 80 11 0000 c0a80ac8 c0a80a0a
```

**UDP-Header** (8Byte): Source=1919, Dest=1920, Length=1278(04fe) = Data + 8, Checksum 2Byte NOT CALCULATED in example!!!

```
077f 0780 003e 9672
```

**DataPayload**: 1270 Byte of raw data

```
0a9f....
```

Using this as datagram you actually should not use `connectToHost()` but use the `writeDatagram()` and now probably working by signal invoked `readyRead()` slot with `hasPendingDatagrams()` and `readDatagram()`.

Comment: If your payload is 1246 bytes you are good with just changing the type in the Ethernet header, if your payload is 1270 byes, then you will have to rewrite the packet generation.

Comment: Yep, turns out we changed the Ethernet frame field from the Length to the EtherType...packets are being received just fine. readyRead() and writeDaramgra() are working just fine, I am no longer connecting to the host, etc. All solid now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with Qt but for BSD socket API, I usually use bind to set my receive port but don't use connect for UDP connection especially when using different ports like your 1919 vs 1920
For socket API, use sendto() for sending packets with the target IP/port.

So, try commenting out connectToHost and directly use writeDatagram when sending.

Comment: I agree. Connect does not make much sense on UDP.
Some implementation fails to `recvfrom` if you did not send anything, so you can `sendto` anything to anywhere...

What about trying a basic UDP receiver, e.g. `netcat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with nc and verify packets receiving from FPGA

```
nc -lu 192.168.10.10 1920
```

If you got packets with nc, the problem is in your Qt code. You could try Qt::DirectConnection in the last (optional) argument of connect. maybe youre blocking current thread and program counter never reaches event loop anymore and thus no slots will be called actually.

Comment: It looks like netcat is not receiving anything. I had to use "lup" as the flags because it is a UDP port. Does this mean the NIC or OS is dropping the packets?

Comment: -p is used to specify source port of out coming packets, you should just use -lu for receiving udp packets from network.

Comment: Also, please verify there is no ICMP "Unreachable" or some other ICMP error packets from your computer to FPGA. Maybe OS inform the sender why it dropped a packet.

Comment: No ICMP packets going out. Netcat will not let me use "lu" (I get the error "UDP listen needs -p arg"). "lup" and "lp" don't produce anything.

Comment: @MattDavBen lookat http://serverfault.com/questions/207683/listen-to-udp-data-on-local-port-with-netcat
test with nc -ul  1920